# double value contains 'm' at the end while printing in google benchmarks table

Tags: benchmarking, lru, google-benchmark

This is my Benchmark method.

```cpp
static void BM_LRU(benchmark::State &state) {
    lru_cache* cache = lru_init(state.range(0));
    std::vector<int> pages = generateRandomPages(state.range(1));

    for (auto _ : state) {
        lru_put_array(cache, pages.data(), pages.size());
    }

    double hitRatio = lru_get_hit_ratio(cache);

    // std::cout<<hitRatio<<std::endl;
    state.counters["Hit Ratio"] = hitRatio;

    lru_destroy(cache);
}
```

I am calling this method by,

```cpp
BENCHMARK(BM_LRU)->ArgsProduct({{3, 5, 10}, {1000, 10000, 100000}})->Unit(benchmark::kMillisecond);
```

When i run the benchmark file i get,

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                 Time             CPU   Iterations  Hit Ratio
----------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_LRU/3/1000         0.232 ms        0.232 ms         3039          0
BM_LRU/5/1000         0.239 ms        0.239 ms         2903         4m
BM_LRU/10/1000        0.243 ms        0.243 ms         2898      0.013
BM_LRU/3/10000         2.33 ms         2.33 ms          301       2.4m
BM_LRU/5/10000         2.42 ms         2.42 ms          292       4.5m
BM_LRU/10/10000        2.45 ms         2.45 ms          287       9.1m
BM_LRU/3/100000        23.4 ms         23.4 ms           30      2.93m
BM_LRU/5/100000        24.2 ms         24.2 ms           29      5.02m
BM_LRU/10/100000       24.5 ms         24.5 ms           29    0.01006
```

When i printed the values it was fine but in the benchmark table a 'm' appears at the end for some values.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The output behavior can't be changed. The printer of user counters calls [`HumanReadableNumber()`](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/361e8d1cfe0c6c36d30b39f1b61302ece5507320/src/console_reporter.cc#L179) that cannot be tuned like you want it. Values less than 0.01 are [printed](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/361e8d1cfe0c6c36d30b39f1b61302ece5507320/src/string_util.cc#L100) with the "m" suffix - "milli".

Comment: note this is only true for the console reporter.  the CSV and JSON reporters do not use this for reporting user counters.